# How to restrict HTML column elements based on maximum value of field in array of objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

I have a pug template that receives an array of objects from Node/mongo/express. Based on the maximum value of one the fields (not length), I need to restrict some columns in an html table.

For example, the objects rendered from node might look like this

```
{
    quantity: 4,
    years: 6
},
{
    quantity: 78,
    years: 2
}
```

I would then need to restrict the number of 'year' columns in my table to be 6. I'm not sure what the best way is to do this, whether to render an additional 'max' variable in node, whether I can do this in pug, or if I should use some client-side js. In (very) pseudo-code, I want something like this...

```
forEach(Math.max(project.output.years)){
     ...create an html table 'year' column
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to do here?  I'm unclear if you want to find the max number of years across your data or restrict the number of columns generated in a table.  The title says the latter, the question text says the former.

Comment: @Graham Both - I want to restrict the number of columns to the max number of years. It's doing both together that's causing me the problem - should I preload the 'max years' as a variable in Node to render in the template and then restrict in the html somehow, should/can I use client-side JS to both ascertain the max and create the DOM elements from that....etc.

Comment: If you use pug the best practice is to use node to limit the max years then loop the columns using `each` in pug.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if pug is the right tool for doing this kind of data manipulation.

From the nodejs side, you could use a reducer to find the maximum years value and send it down with the rest of your data.

```js
const data = [{
    quantity: 4,
    years: 6,
  },
  {
    quantity: 78,
    years: 2,
  },
]

const maxYears = data.reduce((acc, current) => current.years >= acc ? current.years + acc : acc, 0)

console.log(maxYears) // 6
```

Or make the reducer a bit more flexible in terms of which field it accesses to make a comparison.

```js
const data = [{
    quantity: 4,
    years: 6,
  },
  {
    quantity: 78,
    years: 2,
  },
]

const findMaxVal = (property, data) =>
  data.reduce(
    (accumulator, current) =>
    current[property] > accumulator ? current[property] : accumulator,
    0
  )

console.log(findMaxVal("years", data)) // 6
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways to find the max, but the easiest is:

```
var maxYears = 0;
for(var i = 0 ; i < data.length ; i++){
  if( data[i].years > maxYears ){
    maxYears = data[i].years;
  }
}
```

(I'm assuming that the array you have all those objects in is called `data`)

Then you can pass maxYears into the pug template and do this:

```
table
  tr
    - var col = 0;
    while col < maxYears
      td(colIndex= col++)
```

This will produce a table that looks like this for `maxYears = 3`:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td colIndex='0'></td>
    <td colIndex='1'></td>
    <td colIndex='2'></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Just repeat that loop for every row.